# Howto read Range.Top in Excel interop

Tags: c#, .net, excel, com, com-interop

Range in the Excel Interop library has `Left` and `Top` properties. These are of type `Object` as stated on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.top.aspx). Trying to cast the result to float gives an error.

Code:

```
var lastcell = sheet.Cells[row, 1] as Excel.Range;
var topOffset = (float)(lastcell.Top);
```

Error:

> Specified cast is not valid.

How can I retrieve the value as a float (or double..)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I beileve the results is a double rather than a float so:

```
var topOffset = (double)(lastcell.Top);
```

should work.